# Is a 2006 Mac Mini’s processor upgradeable to a Core 2 Duo?

Tags: mac, cpu, upgrade, mac-mini, intel-core2

I have a Mac Mini with Core Solo 1.5GHz, 512mb RAM, 60gb HDD, etc... I know, it's very old but since it's lying around here, I wanted to bump it up for general usage and some experimental iPhone development. Also, Snow Leopard can't be installed as it doesn't have enough RAM. I browsed around but I'm not sure if this Mac Mini's motherboard accepts a Core2Duo (at least a 2.0GHz). If anyone could inform me which generation of Core2Duo it still accepts, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems so

http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/faq_core/mac-mini-core-upgrade-processor.html

http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/systems/mac_mini_core_2_duo_swaps.html

Comment: Thank you, the second link was very good.
So it is indeed possible to upgrade from Core Solo to a Core2Duo T7x00 Merom.